# Android build fails `Could not determine artifacts for com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.12.1: Skipped due to earlier error`

Tags: android, flutter

I try to build my app with Flutter for Android. Locally, I have no problems. But when I try to build with a CI machine like Codemagic or GitHub Actions, the build fails:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeProdReleaseAssets'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:prodReleaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not determine artifacts for com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.12.1: Skipped due to earlier error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I'm using Flutter `2.10.5`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to the [`video_player`](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package. I used the following version in my `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  video_player: ^2.1.12

dependency_overrides:
  video_player:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/cbenhagen/plugins.git
      path: packages/video_player/video_player
      ref: video_player_macos_new
```

Removing the dependency override for `video_player` and upgrade to the newest `video_player` version (in my case `2.4.2`) fixed it.